# Vim - Sort each line of numbers in a file?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file like the following:

```
Pallets
24 1 345 232 345 1 432 45 0 3

some text
more text

COPIES
542 11,456 1,576 1,212 13,229 46,035 9,061 10,642 13,044
CHARGES
225.45 4,464.90 613.91 511.73 5,140.22 17,532.10 3,473.52 4,059.68 5,064.39
```

Is it possible to do a sort on each line that is a list of numbers?

So something like (i imagine):

If matches pattern /^\d+/ then sort that line.

Is this possible?

**Edit.** Here would be the output.

```
Pallets
0 1 1 232 24 3 345 345 432 45 

some text
more text

COPIES
542 1,212 1,576 9,061 10,642 11,456 13,044 13,229 46,035 
CHARGES
225.45 511.73 613.91 3,473.52 4,059.68 4,464.90 5,064.39 5,140.22 17,532.10
```

**Edit.** Here is what I got so far (ignoring the commas and fractional parts)

```
%s/\n\(\d.*\)\n/\rSTART\r\1\rEND\r/
g/^\d/ s/ /\r/g
#Throwing away decimal for now..
g/^\d/ s/,\|\.\d\+//
g/START/+,/END/- sort
g/START/+,/END/- s/\n/ /
%s/ END$//
g/^START/d
```

Comment: your expected output is? pls paste it in the question.

Comment: Does it need to be vim?  Could it be in something more amenable to it like Perl?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose any unix tool would do.. I just usually do this stuff in vim (or sed/awk).

Comment: You could do this in Python with a pretty simple script. `' '.join(sorted(line.split()))` would work for the lines you're interested in.

Answer (score 4):

You can first split the records into separate lines, sort them, then re-join:

```
:s/ /\r/g
:'[,']sort
:'[,']join
```

If you don't use space as the delimiter, you have to use `:s` to re-join:

```
:'[,']s/\n/,/
```

The `'[,']` handily selects the modified range (from the initial splitting of the line), so you don't need to work with line numbers or introduce BEGIN..END guards artificially.

Comment: I don't think he uses a ',' as a delimiter. It's a space. The comma is for every 3 digits.

Comment: Sorry, the second line was supposed to be space delimited (like the others).

Comment: Yeah but the search and replace expression in the answer needs to change.

Comment: What does this mean? `:'[,']sort` and `:'[,']s/\n/,/`

Comment: @anthonybell: Thanks for the clarification, I've adapted my answer.

Comment: All together one one line: `:g/^\d/s/\s/\r/g|sil exe "'[,']!sort -n"|'[,']j`. Note this uses system `sort` command

Comment: What is the reason for using system sort instead of built-in sort?

Comment: @Ben `:sort` even with the `n` flag will not sort correctly because of the commas and decimals. Using the system (mine is GNU) sort, i.e. `sort -n`, we can overcome this.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. Then you wouldn't need to reformat them first, either.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd use setline(), split(), and sort() from a global `:g` command.

This is more difficult than it appears at first glance because we need to convert the numbers to floats, and also we need to strip out the commas:

```
g#^\d\+#call setline('.', join(sort(map(split(getline('.')), "str2float(substitute(v:val, ',', '', 'g'))"), 'n')))
```

- getline() gets the current line's content
- split() gets each number by itself in a list of strings
- map() applies an operation to each string in the list

  - substitute() strips off the commas
  - str2float() converts it to a number
- sort() sorts the list of numbers
- join() is to join the list back together to a single string
- setline() is to replace the line content

*Edit:* This relies on the 'n' flag of the `sort()` function, which was added in 7.4.341 to allow sorting numbers rather than always treating them as strings. In older versions of Vim, you can still use this solution, but rather than 'n' pass in a function name that can compare the items. See `:help sort()` for details on how to create such a function, and an example. Note, using a function in this way, would also allow you to keep comma formatting and the like, whereas the direct solution given above strips out the commas and always adds a decimal even when the original line had an integer only.

*Alternative:* If you don't like using the set/getline functions, you can also do the whole thing in one substitute command which works the same way to do a replacement matching entire lines starting with a number:

```
:%s/^\d\+.*/\=join(sort(map(split(submatch(0)), "str2float(substitute(v:val, ',', '', 'g'))"), 'n'))/e
```

This works in the same way, but uses `submatch(0)` instead of `getline('.')` and relies on expression substitution with the `\=` item. See `:help submatch()` and `:help sub-replace-expression` for details. I doubt there is a significant speed difference so which method you use is more of a personal preference.

Comment: `sort()` uses the string representation of each item to sort on, so I do not think this will work correctly here unless you pass in a custom function. You can also avoid the `setline()`/`getline()` business by using `:s/.*/\=` with `submatch(0)`. See `:h sort(` and `:h :s\=`.

Comment: There is a (new, maybe?) argument you can pass to sort to force it to sort numerically. That's the 'n' flag in my call to sort() above. I'll make a note.

Comment: Here is the substitute version of your solution: `g/^\d\+/s/.*/\=join(sort(map(split(submatch(0)), "str2float(substitute(v:val, ',', '', 'g'))"), 'n'))`. I can not test it as my Vim is not new enough, so here be dragons!

Comment: It works. I tweaked it to remove the `:g` entirely and incorporated your suggestion as an alternative. Thanks!